# NSDate returning null on device not on simulator

Tags: ios, null, ios-simulator, nsdate

I posted this question before and got an answer that worked, for one night only :(

I have this code:

```
NSLog(@"timeStringsArray2 %@", timeStringsArray2);

    //3. Create NSDateFormatter
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"MST"]];

    //4. Get strings from Array
    NSString *openDateString = (NSString*)[timeStringsArray2 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *closeDateString = (NSString*)[timeStringsArray2 objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"someDateString %@,%@", openDateString,closeDateString);

    //5. Get month & day of current date
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar* calendario = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* components = [calendario components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];

    [components year]; // gives you year

    //6. Make new strings with year 0001 + original time
    NSString *adjustedOpenDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%ld-%ld %@", @"2013", (long)[components month], (long)[components day], openDateString];
    NSString *adjustedCloseDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%ld-%ld %@", @"2013", (long)[components month], (long)[components day],closeDateString];
    NSLog(@"adjustedString %@", adjustedCloseDateString);

    //7. Use Date Formatter to convert adjusted strings to NSDates
    NSDate *openDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:adjustedOpenDateString];
    NSDate *closeDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:adjustedCloseDateString];

    NSLog(@"DEALWITHTIMESTRINGS = open, now, close %@,%@,%@", openDate,[NSDate date], closeDate);
```

it logs this:

```
timeStringsArray2 (
    "8:00AM",
    "6:30PM" ) 2013-08-12 
09:28:49 p.m.:316[7008:2311] +[TimeComparator dealWithTimeStrings2:] [Line 59] someDateString 8:00AM,6:30PM 2013-08-12 
09:28:49 p.m.:320[7008:2311] +[TimeComparator dealWithTimeStrings2:] [Line 73] adjustedString 2013-8-12 6:30PM 2013-08-12 
09:28:49 p.m.:325[7008:2311] +[TimeComparator dealWithTimeStrings2:] [Line 79] DEALWITHTIMESTRINGS = open, now, close (null),2013-08-13 04:28:49 a.m. +0000,(null)
```

I was suggested to change the format to hh:mma.  I did and it worked briefly last night, for a couple of runs maybe.  This morning it stopped working, returning null again.  Any other ideas?

The only pattern I find is that it works on the simulator but not on any device.  In the simulator, all dates come back just fine, open and close.  But when i run it on the device, all dates come back null.

Comment: When parsing fixed format date strings you should set the date formatter's locale to the special locale of `en_US_POSIX`. Apple has a whole Technical Q&A on this.

Comment: BTW - on your device, is the time set to 12 or 24-hour format? See Settings, General, Date & Time.

Comment: Found it: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html thanks!